# What does ex - muslim pakistani mean grammatically. Does it mean ex muslim ex pakistani?

Tags: phrase-meaning

If ex is followed by two words or adjectives, then does ex imply to the first adjective only or it will be applied to second adjective aswell e.g, ex-muslim pakistani.

Comment: Context is important for ambiguous phrases like this. Can you quote the material where you saw this?

Comment: Would you consider the possibility that an ***ex-Norwegian Blue parrot*** might be thus labelled because the parrot had successfully applied for citizenship elsewhere, and was now an alive-and-kicking ***Danish Blue parrot**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers John Cleese might maintain that it is simply an "ex-parrot".

Comment: @WS2: I'm with Michael Palin on that one. It was only *sleeping* at the time, and parrots are famously long-lived, so I expect it's still living somewhere even today. Mind you, I believe Elvis is still with us... :)~

Comment: Why has this question come up twice? Is this a common thing that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhat ambiguous, depending on the context. In this particular case, "Pakistani" would seem to be something intrinsic, a quality that you cannot be an "ex-" of. Furthermore, "Muslim" and "Pakistani" are not inexorably linked; one can be either one and not be the other.

To give a case where "ex" *could* modify both, it seems like the two adjectives would have be strongly related, for example:

"Ex-database programmer"

It *could be* that one no longer a programmer at all, or it simply could be that one works as a programmer, but in a different field.

Comment: One could renounce their citizenship, like how Ted Cruz is an ex-Canadian.

Comment: Again, it depends... You can definitely say "Ex-Canadian", because Canada is a political construct, and less of a cultural or ethnic one than Pakistan.

Comment: Chris B. Behrens: Pakistan was an (ill-advised, imho) political construct too. It's just that the redrawn map (and relocation of people) was mainly based on religious affiliation (which wasn't really relevant to Canada).

Comment: No; the hyphen is used to show the major coherence. _A sweet-shop girl_ does not mean the same as _a sweet shop-girl_. An ex-Muslim Pakistani means a Pakistani who used to be a Muslim. / You need to add supporting evidence to answers that could otherwise look like (and even merely be) personal opinion.